# SQL: Seeking an advise for tables structure etc

Tags: mysql, sql

**First what are conditions.** I have people belonging to "small" group. (which in other words means every one has "small_group_id". Then "small" groups form "big" groups (which in other words means "small_groups" may or not have "big_group_id" depending if small group belongs to bigger ot not).

**I want to** create a table structure (that would be used by PHP) for keeping and displaying two following things:

- Public messages (means whoever is regestered or even not will be able to see it). Only author of the message can edit/delete. This is easy part :)
- Private messages WITH defining how private is it. That means privat emessage should have  property a) what small groups can see it b) what big groups can see it (that assumes that all members of big groups will have rights to see it).

Basically the challenge for me is how to design and later work with visibility of those private messages.
My first though was table like: `msgID, msgBody, small_groups_list, big_group_list, authorID` So I store e.g. in `'small_groups_id'` something like `'id_1; id_4; id_10'`, etc and similar for big groups. But then I'm not sure how do I do search through such stored lists when e.g. person belonging to small_group_id = 10 supposed to see that mesage. Also what should be the columns `small_groups_list` and `big_group_list` defenitions/types.

Perhaps there is better way to store such things and using them as well?
That is why I'm here. What would be better practices for such requirements?

(it is going to be implemented on mySQL)

Thank you in advance.

[edit]
I'm pretty unexperienced in SQL and DB things. Please take that into account when answering.

Comment: It would be useful to see an example of a public message and a private message, and how you intend on using them. If you're trying to show a row of data to someone as a message based on THE GROUPS "ID" trying to access something, how are you determining who qualifies to see what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Don't denormalize your data with "array" columns.  That makes it a horror to query, and *even worse* to update.

Instead, you need two separate tables: `small_group_visibility` and `big_group_visibility`. Each of these two tables will consist of `msgID` and `groupID`.  Basically, it's a many-to-many relationship that's pointing out to both the group and the message it is concerned with.

This is a pretty common database pattern.

To query for messages to be displayed, imagine that we have a user whose small groups are (1, 2, 3) and whose large groups are (10, 20).

```
SELECT DISTINCT msgID, msgSubject, msgBody -- and so on
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN small_group_visibility sg
  ON sg.msg_id = m.msg_id
LEFT JOIN big_group_visibility bg
  ON bg.msg_id = m.msg_id
WHERE
  sg.group_id IN (1, 2, 3) OR
  bg.group_id IN (10, 20);
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are saying :) Sounds like each private message may have number of records in each of those tables you talking about? And then when my PHP will need to figure out yes or no for user to see the message I'll just search for msgID for big and samll user's groups in both of tables and if found any -> display the message with that ID?

Comment: Correct.  One message may have any number of records in either table.  You can have a list of the user's relevant groups -- i.e. their small groups and big groups -- and you can do a join against the two group tables.  I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: I've understood beauty of your solution. Thank you very much!